# apollo client onSubscriptionData is not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I'm following the apollo [subscriptions tutorial](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/advanced/subscriptions.html) and my subscription is working, but I'm not getting to use the [onSubscriptionData](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/advanced/subscriptions.html#props) data callback.

Here's my code:

```
const MESSAGE_CREATED = gql`
  subscription {
    messageCreated {
      id
      content
    }
  }
`;

const MyComponent = () => (
  <Subscription
      subscription={MESSAGE_CREATED}
      onSubscriptionData={() => {
        console.log('subs');
      }}
    >
      {({ data, loading }) => {
        if (loading && !data) return <View />;
        return (
          <Text>New comment: {!loading && data.messageCreated.content}</Text>
        );
      }}
    </Subscription>
);
```

I don't get the subs log on my console.

Answer (score 2):

This feature is only available on 'master' branch. I just tested it and 'onSubscriptionData' prop is working as desired. If you wanna test it, you should:

1. Update 'react-apollo' package version to 'master' as follow: **"react-apollo": "apollographql/react-apollo"**
2. Compile TS code executing: **cd node_modules/react-apollo && yarn && yarn compile**
3. Refactor all import paths from 'react-apollo' to 'react-apollo/lib' as follow: **import { Subscription } from 'react-apollo/lib'**

Comment: This really works, but it's not viable for my project.

Comment: I don't have time for waiting this happen in two months

Comment: Check 'subscribeToMore' prop on <Query /> https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/queries.html#render-prop. You could find a live example on https://howtographql.com

Comment: subscribeToMore is an alternative for this gap, but my payload at subscription would be huge.